# Node JS Undefined Variable In Argument

Tags: node.js

```
let args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(' ');
let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
let tellJoke = randomNumber(4);

if (debounce == true){
    return
  }
debounce = true

switch (command) {

  case 'gameid':
    console.log(args.length)
    if(args.length == 1){
      let placeId = args[1]
      console.log(placeId)
      api = await fetch("https://api.roblox.com/universes/get-universe-containing-place?placeid=" + placeId)
      let gameId = await api.json()
      try{
        if(api){
          reply = await message.reply('Game Id: ' + gameId.UniverseId)
          debounce = false
          break;
        }
      }catch(error){
        reply = await message.reply('Something went wrong. ERROR: ' + error);
        debounce = false
        break;
      }

      }
    reply = await message.reply('Something went wrong. Did you write the command correctly?')
    debounce = false
    return
```

It says placeId/arg 1 is undefined when I clearly put the place id there. Does anyone know why this is happening? I've printed/logged the args and length of it and I can say that it should work.

Comment: If `args.length == 1` then `args[1]` is undefined. `args[0]` is the first element in an array (and the only element in an array of length 1).

Comment: It now works. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array index starts from `0`. so if the length of the array is 1 you can access the first element with `args[0]`.

```
let args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(' ');
let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
let tellJoke = randomNumber(4);

if (debounce == true){
    return
  }
debounce = true

switch (command) {

  case 'gameid':
    console.log(args.length)
    if(args.length == 1){
      let placeId = args[0]
      console.log(placeId)
      api = await fetch("https://api.roblox.com/universes/get-universe-containing-place?placeid=" + placeId)
      let gameId = await api.json()
      try{
        if(api){
          reply = await message.reply('Game Id: ' + gameId.UniverseId)
          debounce = false
          break;
        }
      }catch(error){
        reply = await message.reply('Something went wrong. ERROR: ' + error);
        debounce = false
        break;
      }

      }
    reply = await message.reply('Something went wrong. Did you right the command correctly?')
    debounce = false
    return
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes more sense now why it would say undefined.